# Ajax post causes form submit

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a Jquery Json Post that fetches members of a dropdown list based on changes to another Drop down.  In my Create form, dropdowns fill correctly.  On Edit form when the first drop down changes the Edit ActionResult for DB submission is called.  The create actionResult for DB submission is never called in create form. Why the different behaviour? The same js code is used by both forms.  Why is the Edit form acting like a form submission on a Json method post? (Note : This edit form has worked well before i started to add error checking in the Edit actionresult.  I added the RequestVerificationToken as this was the initial error i was receiving, prior to that it worked without including this.)  The error is generated in the PU.Change(function() and i traced it back to the edit action, which has me puzzled.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My Jquery function on DDL selection

```
    //PU Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
    $("#PU").change(function () {
        $("#LevelOne").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "GetlevelOne", // we are calling json method  
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { PU: $("#PU").val(), "__RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val() },

            success: function (levelonelist) {
                // add level one selections for PU to the levelone list

                $.each(levelonelist, function (i, level) {
                    $("#LevelOne").append('<option value="' + level.Value + '">' +
                        level.Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to load Level one selections.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
```

The method in the controller

```
     [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult GetlevelOne(string PU)
        {

            var levelonelist = new List<SelectListItem>();

            var Getlevelonelist = (from y in db.EfficiencyLevelDrills
                                    where y.PU == PU && y.LevelNo == 2
                                    select y).ToList();

            levelonelist.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "Select", Text = "Select" });
            for (int x = 0; x < Getlevelonelist.Count; x++)
            {
                SelectListItem item = new SelectListItem { Value = Getlevelonelist[x].High, Text = Getlevelonelist[x].High };
                if (levelonelist.All(i => i.Value != item.Value))
                {
                    levelonelist.Add(item);
                }

            }
            return Json(new SelectList(levelonelist, "Value", "Text"));
        }
```

The actionResult that is fired generating an error.  The ModelState is invalid during processing, returning the view instead of the list items, generating the error in my jquery function

```
  [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "ID,Year,Month,Week,PU,LevelOne,LevelTwo,LevelThree,Shift,VarianceType,ReasonGroup,ReasonCode,Comments,Type,Hours,LastupdateBy,LastUpdateDate")] Efficiencyweeklyreason efficiencyweeklyreason)
        {
            var saveready = 1;
            var savemessage = "";
            if (efficiencyweeklyreason.Week == 0 || efficiencyweeklyreason.Week > 52) { saveready = 0; savemessage = "Week Number must be between 1 and 52 ; "; }
            if (efficiencyweeklyreason.PU == "Select") { saveready = 0; savemessage = "Must Select PU; "; }
            if (efficiencyweeklyreason.LevelOne == "Select") { saveready = 0; savemessage = savemessage + "Must Select Level one; "; }
            if (efficiencyweeklyreason.LevelTwo == "Select") { saveready = 0; savemessage = savemessage + "Must Select Level two; "; }
            if (efficiencyweeklyreason.ReasonGroup == "Select") { saveready = 0; savemessage = savemessage + "Must Select Reason Group; "; }
            if (efficiencyweeklyreason.ReasonCode == "Select") { saveready = 0; savemessage = savemessage + "Must Select Reason Code; "; }
            if (efficiencyweeklyreason.Shift == "Select") { saveready = 0; savemessage = savemessage + "Must Select Shift; "; }

            if (ModelState.IsValid && saveready == 1)

            {
                db.Entry(efficiencyweeklyreason).State = EntityState.Modified;
                efficiencyweeklyreason.LastUpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                efficiencyweeklyreason.LastupdateBy = lUser.UserNetworkName;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("List", new { PUSelected = efficiencyweeklyreason.PU, Year = efficiencyweeklyreason.Year, Month = efficiencyweeklyreason.Month, Week = efficiencyweeklyreason.Week });
                //return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            // reload the edit screen with meassage about bad data
            LoadListsEdit(efficiencyweeklyreason);
            ViewBag.savecode = "Failure";
            ViewBag.Message = savemessage;
            return View(efficiencyweeklyreason);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue here was the url.  The url was "Efficiencyweeklyreasons/Edit/GetlevelOne". Changing to an absolute URL in my ajax post solved this.

```
url: "/Efficiencyweeklyreasons/GetlevelOne"
```

This Question answered the issue i was having.
[Ajax query not firing, because it's generating the wrong URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/865715/ajax-query-not-firing-because-its-generating-the-wrong-url)